# When do we see for the first time the use of the Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: mathematics, euclidean-geometry

I want to see an exact image of the first use of the Cartesian plane. I guess it came the first time with Descartes.

Comment: No; in Descartes's [Geometry](https://books.google.it/books?id=MB7F32p0y5MC&pg=PA31) the "coordinates" are not orthogonal.

Comment: For a more "modern" use you can see Jan De Witt's commentary (1659); see Albert Grootendorst (editor), [Jan de Witt’s Elementa Curvarum Linearum Liber Secundus](https://books.google.it/books?id=wujlBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA71) (2010).

Comment: Astroman what do you mean by "the Cartesian plane"? By definition I would tend to answer "Descartes", but as Mauro pointed out this isn't the plane we use today.

Comment: In some sense coordinates were implicit in Apollonius' Conics.

Comment: I mean the plane that we use today, when do we see it for the first time? And why do we call this plane cartesian?

Comment: @Astroman For the same reason that even though we say $F=ma$ (or perhaps $F=dp/dt$) is Newton's second law, you won't see either of those anywhere in Newton's writings.

Comment: So, just because Descartes used equations to represent figures we call him the father of analytical geometry ?

Comment: Does Descartes have any problems that use negative numbers?

Comment: You have to see Carl Boyer, [History of analytic geometry](https://books.google.it/books?id=2T4i5fXZbOYC&printsec=frontcover) (1956 - Dover reprint). It is not a case of "all-or-nothing"; see page 203 : "In point of view, the analytic geometry of Lagrange (1773) comes closer to the modern form of the subject than that of any of his predecessors. It was elementary geometry in analytic language, quite independent of reference to geometric diagrams. Analytic formulas replaced geometric entities, and the calculations were carried out with full generality."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways to answer this depending on what "Cartesian plane" means. Most literally, Cartesius is the Latinization of Descartes name, so one can look at [pictures in Descartes's La Geometrie](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-xEExWlptL1k/TwvqJ80sl-I/AAAAAAAAAio/sQ52gE44L08/s1600/La-Geometrie-Extract.png), which was the first systematic use of coordinates to solve geometric problems. However, coordinate graphs were introduced before Descartes by Oresme, to plot speed against time for example, [Oresme's were bar graphs](https://web.archive.org/web/20210914052837/http://www.jpowered.com/graphs-and-charts/images/nicole-oresme-bar-charts-420x615.png) however. [Oresme calls](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/beyond/coursenotes/2006PartIb.pdf) the axes *longitude* and *latitude*, the independent variable *extension*, and the dependent one *intension*.

Descartes got the idea of coordinates from Apollonius of Perga, *abscissas* and *ordinates* are Latin translations of Apollonius's terms. In Conica Apollonius uses tangent to a conic section and its diameter as what we now call coordinate axes, in general they are oblique, draws segments parallel to them, abscissas and ordinates, and relates their lengths by what we now call coordinate equations, he calls them symptoms. He even "changes coordinates" by passing to a new diameter, see [Pierce's Abscissas and Ordinates](http://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1226&context=jhm). A suggestive figure is on p.176 of [Heath's translation](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017073910/https://www.stmarys-ca.edu/sites/default/files/attachments/files/Conic_Sections.pdf), here is another, [from an Arabic copy of book V](http://www.mlahanas.de/Greeks/images/ApolloniusBook.jpg).

However, this was specific to conic sections, Apollonius has no symptoms of this kind for general curves, and his "coordinates" are curve specific, he does not consider even different conics in the same coordinates. So I am not sure if this qualifies as Cartesian. On the other hand, geometrically *Cartesian plane* is the same as *Euclidean plane*, only with numerical labels attached, so perhaps Euclid's diagrams already qualify.