# Which was the first coordinate system? And why was it used?

Tags: geometry, descartes

I've been researching the motivation behind the invention of the Cartesian Co-ordinate system. But I was wondering, which coordinate system was the first to be invented? Was it the Spherical Co-ordinate system? And if yes, why was it needed?

Comment: The first coordinate systems were linear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do we see for the first time the use of the Cartesian coordinates?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2378/when-do-we-see-for-the-first-time-the-use-of-the-cartesian-coordinates)

Comment: Do you consider the description of stars in the sky in terms of angles to be a "coordinate system"?

Comment: Does it have a name? As in, is it a specific coordinate system.